# PHP or WAMP not sure what

Tags: php, wamp

I have installed WAMP server 2.0 with (PHP 5.4.3). After installing WAMP I have restarted all the services and can open

- `phpinfo()` - it is showing up fine
- phpmyadmin - it is also showing up fine.. i can play with database..

however when run simple php file in chrome I could see the code rather than result. below is the code i am trying..

```
<?php
echo "hello world";
?>
```

below is the link to file which I am trying to access via chrome.
file:///C:/WAMP/www/hello%20world.php

Comment: Make sure you go to http://127.0.0.1/hello%20world.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Make sure you have started apache
- Try `http://localhost/hello_horld.php`

Comment: Glad to help :) Make sure you accept the most helpful answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

To run this script, start a browser use  URL `http://localhost/your_file.php` or `http://127.0.0.1/your_file.php`

PHP is a server-side technology (instead of client-side technology like JavaScript). The PHP statements `<?php ... ?>` are processed in the server, and the results returned to the client (browser). so you need to use it through server not direct